# Adding shaded polygon to chemfig schemes

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig, annotations

I have the following chemical reaction scheme with MWE below:

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
P \arrow(P--Q){<=>[$\mathrm{k_{pq}}$]} Q
\arrow{<=>[$\mathrm{k_{qs}}$]}[30] S \arrow(S--T){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{st}}$]}[-30] T
\arrow(@Q--R){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{qr}}$]}[-30] R
\arrow(@R--@T){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{rt}}$]}
\arrow(@T--U){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{tu}}$]} U
\arrow(@U--V){->[$\mathrm{k_{uv}}$]} V
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

***How can I added a shaded polygon to a particular scheme?*** As an example see image below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chemfig` uses TikZ, and you can place normal `\draw` macros in a `\chemmove`. The benefit of this is that the node names are directly available, so no additional markup in the form of `\tikzmark`s is needed.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
%\schemedebug{true} % uncomment to see node names
\schemestart
P \arrow(P--Q){<=>[$\mathrm{k_{pq}}$]} Q
\arrow{<=>[$\mathrm{k_{qs}}$]}[30] S \arrow(S--T){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{st}}$]}[-30] T
\arrow(@Q--R){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{qr}}$]}[-30] R
\arrow(@R--@T){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{rt}}$]}
\arrow(@T--U){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{tu}}$]} U
\arrow(@U--V){->[$\mathrm{k_{uv}}$]} V
%
\chemmove{%
  \draw [red,thick] ([shift={(-5pt,1em)}]Q.north west) -- ([yshift=1em]S.north) --
                    ([yshift=1em]T.north) -- ([shift={(5pt,1em)}]U.north east) --
                    ([shift={(5pt,-1.5em)}]U.south east) --
                    ([yshift=-1.5em]T.south) -- ([yshift=-2em]R.south) --
                    ([shift={(-5pt,-2em)}]Q.south west) -- cycle;
}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works fine, but would there be an option to arrange the polygon such that the polygon is behind the reaction scheme?

Comment: @nxkryptor Don't know, the obvious method using the `backgrounds` library didn't work. I'd suggest asking a new question about that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using tikzmark:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
P \arrow(P--Q){<=>[$\mathrm{k_{pq}}$]} \tikzmark{myA}Q
\arrow{<=>[$\mathrm{k_{qs}}$]}[30] \tikzmark{myB}S \arrow(S--T){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{st}}$]}[-30] T\tikzmark{myC}
\arrow(@Q--R){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{qr}}$]}[-30] R \tikzmark{myD}
\arrow(@R--@T){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{rt}}$]}
\arrow(@T--U){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{tu}}$]} U \tikzmark{myE}
\arrow(@U--V){->[$\mathrm{k_{uv}}$]} V
\schemestop

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \coordinate (A) at ([xshift=-5pt,yshift=-10pt]myA);
  \coordinate (B) at ([xshift=-5pt,yshift=15pt]myA);
  \coordinate (C) at ([xshift=5pt,yshift=20pt]myB);
  \coordinate (D) at ([xshift=5pt,yshift=15pt]myC);
  \coordinate (E) at ([xshift=5pt,yshift=-10pt]myC);
  \coordinate (F) at ([xshift=-5pt,yshift=-15pt]myD);
  \coordinate (G) at ([xshift=5pt,yshift=15pt]myE);
  \coordinate (H) at ([xshift=5pt,yshift=-10pt]myE);

  \draw[red,thick] (A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--(G)--(H)--(E)--(F)--(A);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]