# Move shaded polygon behind chemfig schemes

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig, draw, annotations

I have the following chemical reaction scheme with a shaded polygon (using [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405702/72911)) as shown in MWE below:

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
%\schemedebug{true} % uncomment to see node names
\schemestart
P \arrow(P--Q){<=>[$\mathrm{k_{pq}}$]} Q
\arrow{<=>[$\mathrm{k_{qs}}$]}[30] S \arrow(S--T){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{st}}$]}[-30] T
\arrow(@Q--R){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{qr}}$]}[-30] R
\arrow(@R--@T){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{rt}}$]}
\arrow(@T--U){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{tu}}$]} U
\arrow(@U--V){->[$\mathrm{k_{uv}}$]} V
%
\chemmove{%
  \draw [red,fill=red,fill opacity=0.5,thick] ([shift={(-5pt,1em)}]Q.north west) -- ([yshift=1em]S.north) --
                    ([yshift=1em]T.north) -- ([shift={(5pt,1em)}]U.north east) --
                    ([shift={(5pt,-1.5em)}]U.south east) --
                    ([yshift=-1.5em]T.south) -- ([yshift=-2em]R.south) --
                    ([shift={(-5pt,-2em)}]Q.south west) -- cycle;
}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

However, the shaded polygon is overlaid on the reaction scheme as shown in the figure. How do I move back the shaded polygon to the back of the reaction scheme? I need the reaction scheme placed on the shaded polygon. Can this be done?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could put it on a background layer, but why bother? Does it matter if it is behind? Or only that it looks as if it is behind? If the latter, what about the following?

[image: looks behind?]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
%\schemedebug{true} % uncomment to see node names
\schemestart
P \arrow(P--Q){<=>[$\mathrm{k_{pq}}$]} Q
\arrow{<=>[$\mathrm{k_{qs}}$]}[30] S \arrow(S--T){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{st}}$]}[-30] T
\arrow(@Q--R){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{qr}}$]}[-30] R
\arrow(@R--@T){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{rt}}$]}
\arrow(@T--U){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{tu}}$]} U
\arrow(@U--V){->[$\mathrm{k_{uv}}$]} V
%
\chemmove{%
  \draw [red,fill=red,fill opacity=0.5,blend mode=multiply,thick] ([shift={(-5pt,1em)}]Q.north west) -- ([yshift=1em]S.north) --
                    ([yshift=1em]T.north) -- ([shift={(5pt,1em)}]U.north east) --
                    ([shift={(5pt,-1.5em)}]U.south east) --
                    ([yshift=-1.5em]T.south) -- ([yshift=-2em]R.south) --
                    ([shift={(-5pt,-2em)}]Q.south west) -- cycle;
}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice all your works. +1 everybody.

Answer (score 5):

Just in case you really want it behind, there is always the eso-pic rescue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}
%\schemedebug{true} % uncomment to see node names
\schemestart
%
P \arrow(P--Q){<=>[$\mathrm{k_{pq}}$]} Q
\arrow{<=>[$\mathrm{k_{qs}}$]}[30] S \arrow(S--T){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{st}}$]}[-30] T
\arrow(@Q--R){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{qr}}$]}[-30] R
\arrow(@R--@T){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{rt}}$]}
\arrow(@T--U){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{tu}}$]} U
\arrow(@U--V){->[$\mathrm{k_{uv}}$]} V
%
% \chemmove{%
% }
\schemestop
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
  \draw [red,fill=red,opacity=0.5,thick,semitransparent] ([shift={(-5pt,1em)}]Q.north west) -- ([yshift=1em]S.north) --
                    ([yshift=1em]T.north) -- ([shift={(5pt,1em)}]U.north east) --
                    ([shift={(5pt,-1.5em)}]U.south east) --
                    ([yshift=-1.5em]T.south) -- ([yshift=-2em]R.south) --
                    ([shift={(-5pt,-2em)}]Q.south west) -- cycle;
}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the example at hand, @cfr's solution is probably simpler, but if the foreground has colors, this method might be considered.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use `on background layer` with the relevant Ti*k*Z library? Or doesn't that work here? (I didn't try it.)

Comment: @cfr It does not work, at least not without modifying the chemfig package.

Comment: I guess because it draws everything in separate `tikzpicture`s :(.

Comment: @cfr I tried playing with these layers for quite a while, but inside the `\schemestart` ... `\schemestop` Ti*k*Z commands do not work, and afterwards it's too late. Yet chemfig is kind enough to remember its pictures. In the end I gave up and went for the brutal eso-pic option. As I said, this makes real sense only if you use colors (including white) that are not to be shaded. Of course, there *might* be a sneaky `every picture` option, but I did not manage to find any.

Comment: I looked at the code for `\chemmove` and that's why I said it is starting new `tikzpicture`s. So you can't go behind what's already typeset, regardless if you remember it or not.

Comment: @cfr I agree but that's not what I meant. What I meant is that I will always be a newbie to Ti*k*Z and I would not be too surprised if there was a global option that would allow one to to put things in the background. After all, eso-pic achieves this (of course in a completely different way). Anyway, thanks for your feedback!

Comment: We're almost all perpetual newbies to Ti*k*Z ;).

Comment: @cfr That's probably why it's so much fun to play with Ti*k*Z. I also didn't know the blend mode trick before I learned it from your answer.

Comment: `blend mode` seems almost completely ignored. I'm not sure why. It is rather PDF-viewer dependent, but people happily use other things of that kind, so that doesn't seem sufficient explanation.